# CWAC error: Unable to get provider com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I was integrating CWAC StreamProvider to my code, but after run my code, I saw Unable to get provider com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider in  logcat.  I couldn't solve it from solutions on internet, because I found only a few solutions which not works for me.

**Provider**

```
     <provider
        android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider"
        android:authorities="cz.revelio.tomiookamura"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data                
       android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**Variables for class**

```
     private static final String AUTHORITY = "cz.revelio.tomiookamura";
private static final Uri PROVIDER = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY);
private static String ASSET_PATHS;
```

**OnCreate method**
defined longClickListener for share

```
     button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putInt("ButtonId", v.getId());
                        String btnName = "share_"+soubor;
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(btnName, params);
                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        ASSET_PATHS = "assets/" + soubor+".mp3";
                            setShareIntent();


                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

**Functions for share**

```
      private Intent setShareIntent(){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("audio/*");

    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {""});
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hláška");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getURI());
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    return shareIntent;
}

private Uri getURI(){
    return(PROVIDER
            .buildUpon()
            .appendPath(StreamProvider.getUriPrefix(AUTHORITY))
            .appendPath(ASSET_PATHS)
            .build());
}
```

**Error**

```
2019-01-15 22:32:54.081 29858-29858/cz.revelio.tomiookamura E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cz.revelio.tomiookamura, PID: 29858
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse com.commonsware.cwac.provider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse com.commonsware.cwac.provider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
    at com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider.attachInfo(StreamProvider.java:208)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not build strategy for assets
    at com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider.parseStreamStrategy(StreamProvider.java:418)
```

**Provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <assets name="assets" path=""/>
  </paths>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:authorities="cz.revelio.tomiookamura"
```

Your value here is: `cz.revelio.tomiookamura`.

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.anothergamedesigner.CatVimeoTest";
```

Your value here is: `com.anothergamedesigner.CatVimeoTest`.

These values are not the same. They need to be the same.

---

Also, replace:

```
<assets name="assets" path=""/>
```

with:

```
<asset name="assets" path=""/>
```

Comment: But unfortunatelly i still have the same problem after edit my code

Comment: @Knihaman: What is the content of your `provider_paths` XML resource?

Comment: I edited my question, on the end is now provider_paths.xml

Comment: @Knihaman: See updated answer. `<assets>` need to be `<asset>`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, this solved my problem. Now it's writing that file is bigger then 20Mb, for 300kb mp3, but that's offtopic problem.